# Should I worry about "window is not defined" JSLint strict mode error?

Tags: javascript, global, jslint, strict

This won't pass JSLint in strict mode:

```
"use strict";
(function (w) {
   w.alert(w);
}(window));
```

The error--from jslint.com--looks like this:

Problem at line 4 character 3: 'window' is not defined.

```
}(window));
```

*Implied global: window 4*

Do I need to tell JSLint to ignore the error, or am I seriously doing something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try adding the following:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
/*global window */
```

(or check *Assume a browser* checkbox).

The first line adds general browser support. The second line declares *window* to be a global variable.

From the documentation:

> The browser option does not include the aliases of the global object, *window* and *self*.

Comment: Globals are not allowed if we are using es6 jslint

Answer (score 16):

Got it, after a false start.  I first tried this:

```
/* global window */
```

... which didn't work.  This did:

```
/*global window */
```

The space after the initial asterisk turns out to be important.

Comment: This worked to me, while using Visual Source Code v. 1.20.1:

    /* global console, require, window */ (even with the whitespace)