# JSLint ES6 window in not defined

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am using latest JSLint and getting JSLint to complain about the window is not defined. With es6 JSLint directive globals are not allowed.

```
/*jslint es6*/
import AppConst from "@/constants/app.constant.js";
const applicationConfig = {
    showMobileView: null,
    is_iphone: null,
    imageryViewUseSubnav: null
};
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    applicationConfig.showMobileView = utilityService.is_small_device();
    applicationConfig.imageryViewUseSubnav = 
    utilityService.is_small_device();
    applicationConfig.is_iphone = utilityService.is_iphone();
});
export default applicationConfig;
```

Comment: This might be a [duplicate of this, or it may answer your Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853473/should-i-worry-about-window-is-not-defined-jslint-strict-mode-error)

Comment: Globals are not allowed if we export module.

Comment: No dice on the answer? Let me know if that doesn't answer your question & I'll see if I can't add something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell JSLint you're in a browser context.

You had a few other errors -- unimported `utilityService`, no `Object.freeze` on your exported object, etc.

If I clean them all up, I get the below, which lints on today's [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com) without any additional changes:

```
/*jslint browser */

// this wasn't used: import AppConst from "@/constants/app.constant.js";
import utilityService from "@/somewhere/file.js";

const applicationConfig = {
    showMobileView: null,
    is_iphone: null,
    imageryViewUseSubnav: null
};
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    applicationConfig.showMobileView = utilityService.is_small_device();
    applicationConfig.imageryViewUseSubnav =
            utilityService.is_small_device();
    applicationConfig.is_iphone = utilityService.is_iphone();
});
export default Object.freeze(applicationConfig);
```